# how to make two dependant fields by jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

this code like changing profile username in facebook
 i have a problem with this code:

```
$(function(){
 var uid = 1;
 var name_available=0;
 var password_ok=0;
$('#name,#password').bind('keyup',function(){
  var name = $('#name').val();
  var password = $('#password').val();

   if(/[^a-zA-Z_\.0-9]+/.test(name)){
      $('#result').html('Invalid Charcters');
      name_available = 0;
   }else{
     $.ajax({
       url: 'check_user.ajax.php',
       type: 'POST',
       data: 'name='+name,
       success: function(data){
         if(data){
              $('#result').html('available');
              name_available = 1;
         }else{
              $('#result').html('not available');
              name_available = 0;
         }
       }
     });
   }
     $.ajax({
       url: 'check_user.ajax.php',
       type: 'POST',
       data: 'uid='+uid+'&password='+password,
       success: function(data){
         if(data){
              $('#result2').html('true');
              password_ok = 1;
         }else{
              $('#result2').html('false');
              password_ok = 0;
         }
       }
     });

     if(name_available === 1 && password_ok === 1){
        $('#save').removeAttr('disabled');
     }else{
        $('#save').attr('disabled','disabled');
     }
});
});
```

and the html code is:

```
username:<input type="text" name="name" value="" id="name" /><span id="result"></span><br />

password:<input type="password" name="password" value="" id="password" /><span id="result2"></span><br />

<input type="submit" name="save" value="save changes" id="save" disabled /><br />
```

and the ajax.php oage is:

```
include 'config.php';

if(isset($_POST['name'])){
$name = $_POST['name'];
    if(!empty($name)){
    $sel = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `name`='$name'");
    $num = mysql_num_rows($sel);
    if($num > 0){
        echo false;
    }else{
        echo true;
    }
}else{
  echo false;
}
}else{
echo false;
}

if(isset($_POST['password']) && isset($_POST['uid'])){
$uid      = $_POST['uid'];
$password = md5($_POST['password']);
$sel      = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `id`='$uid' AND `password`='$password'");
$num      = mysql_num_rows($sel);
if($num < 1){
    echo false;
}else{
    echo true;
}
}else{
echo false;
}
```

the code works but not alltimes when change username or password then change user

please help me, its important for me.

Comment: my code is for check if the username is available and if the username available and he typed his (old) password true in this case remove the attribute "disabled" from the submit button -if you don't understand go to your facebook account>> acouunt settings>> username

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, you are trying to check if the username is already taken and imply to the user to enter another one.

I have a similar implementation on my project where in it checks if the ID is already taken and prompts the user to enter another one. Kindly see code below:

```
        var checkIndicatorId = function () {
        var indId = {
            'Id': $('#IdDescriptor').val()
        };

        $('#spnConfirmation img').remove();  **//removes the x or check image** 
        $('#spnConfirmation').append('<img class="icon" src="/CSS/Contents/loader.gif" title="Checking for availability.">');

        $.ajax({   //ajax call for checking data on the server
            url: 'http://localhost:54004/Cd/CheckIndicatorId',
            data: indId,
            type: 'GET',
            contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8'

        }).success(function (result) {   **// on success do this**
            if (result == true) {       **if id is available**
                $('#spnConfirmation img').remove();
                $('#spnConfirmation').append('<img class="icon" src="/CSS/Contents/check.png" title="Id is available.">');
            }else {              **//if is is already taken**
                $('#spnConfirmation img').remove();
                $('#spnConfirmation').append('<img class="icon" src="/CSS/Contents/error.png" title="Id is not available. Please enter another one.">');
            }
        }).error(function () {

        });
    };
```

ADDED:
Backend Code:

```
            var context = new MyContext();
            var result = context.Cd.Count(x => x.IdDescriptor == id);
            if (result < 1)
            {
                return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); //this is where the result is thrown back to the front end
            }
            else
            {
                var recommendedId = context.Cd.OrderByDescending(x => x.IdDescriptor + 1).FirstOrDefault();
                return Json(recommendedId, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);//this is where the result is thrown back to the front end
            }
```

If you have some clarifications or questions please drop a comment and I would gladly help.

Comment: my code is for check if the username is available and if the username available and he typed his (old) password true in this case remove the attribute "disabled" from the submit button

Comment: What you can do is follow the same pattern as to what I have posted. As you can see, I have checked via ajax if the id is already taken. You can do a similar ajax call where you pass on the password of the user then if controller returns true, do a $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled'). This is assuming that it is already disabled the first time.